# Efficient pseudo-code for XY 5x5 plate movement

Tags: c, algorithm

I am creating a code for an XY table with 5x5 holes (see drawing). It has two motors, one for X position, one for Y position. I know the exact location of each hole and created two functions:

NextHoleX(bool Forward)
NextHoleY()

NextHoleX will move left or right to the next hole, depending on the bool.
NextHoleY will move down to the next hole, it can not move up.

What is the most efficient pseudo-code you can think of for going to each hole till you are at the end (right under)?

See image for details:

[image]

Comment: Example, please... or link to a problem

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? What do you mean by "the most efficient pseudo code" and why is the question tagged C? What's wrong with hard-coding the sequence of 24 calls `NextHoleX(true); NextHoleX(true); NextHoleX(true); NextHoleX(true); NextHoleY(); NextHoleX(false); NextHoleX(false); NextHoleX(false); NextHoleX(false);...` and so on

Comment: What is the most efficient way? The one with the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach of Paul Hankin is quite a good one: you start from there, and then you introduce for-loops for describing repetitive actions, e.g. instead of:

```
NextHoleX(true);
NextHoleX(true);
NextHoleX(true);
NextHoleX(true);
```

You write something like:

```
for (int i=0 to 3){
  NextHoleX(true);
}
```

And you go on from there (you'll end up with two nested for-loops).

However, the situation might become complicated when you need to deal with obstacles, or with the situation that you don't know in advance the size of your board. In that case you might need extra functions, like verifying the possibility to move in a certain direction. If this is the case, you might need to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
int act[24] = { 1,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1 };

for(int i=0; i<24; i++) {
    if(act[i] == 2)
        NextHoleY();
    else
        NextHoleX(act[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only can go down and not up, the way shown in your graphic is the most efficient strategy.

Assuming `NextHoleX(1)` means right and `NextHoleX(0)` means left.

```
int matrix[25], j;
size_t len = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]), i;
_Bool flag = 1;

for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++)
{
    j == 5 ? NextHoleY(), flag = !flag, j = -1 : 0;          
    NextHoleX(flag);
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

void NextHoleX(_Bool b) {}   // foo for the sake of the experiment.
void NextHoleY(void) {}      // foo for the sake of the experiment.

int main (void)
{
    int matrix[25], j;
    size_t len = sizeof(matrix) / sizeof(matrix[0]), i;
    _Bool flag = 1;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < len; i++, j++)
    {
        j == 5 ? NextHoleY(), flag = !flag, j = -1 : 0;          
        NextHoleX(flag);
    }
}
```

[Online Test](https://godbolt.org/z/McdGaE)

Note that this question would be more appropriate here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/